# How to ES6 import (SystemJS) after some code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, systemjs

I want to `import` angular, instantiate the AngularJS module, and then import another file that requires that the Angular be already instantiated:

```js
import angular from 'angular';

var app = angular.module('app', []);

import 'src/app.js';

angular.element(window).ready(function(){
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});
```

But Babel compiles it into this (**TLDR**: hoist all imports to the top)

```
System.register([], function (_export2) {
return {
    setters: [],
    execute: function () {
      System.register(['angular', 'src/app.js'], function (_export) {
        var angular, app;
        return {
          setters: [function (_angular) {
            angular = _angular.default;
          }, function (_srcAppJs) {}],
          execute: function () {
            app = angular.module('app', []);
            angular.element(window).ready(function () {
              angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
            });
          }
        };
      });
    }
  };
});
```

---

**UPDATE**: @just-boris

I was well aware of `System.import().then`. The problem is that app.js also `import`s files which make Angular components, which require that the `module` be instantiated.
Example imported file:

```
angular.module('app').controller( [ function () {} ] );
```

`System.import().then` does not wait until the dependency tree 
is resolved, because it has no sense of one.

```
System.import('app').then(function(){
    // But wait, app.js's dependencies aren't resolved!
    // The Angular components aren't loaded yet!
    // The following will throw errors:
    angular.element(window).ready(function(){
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not put the behavior that app.js depends on in, well, app.js? Or one of its dependencies?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why must export/import declarations be on top level in es2015?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34203325/why-must-export-import-declarations-be-on-top-level-in-es2015)

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I would run into the same problem. See edits.

Answer (score 2):

By design, all import statements should be available for static analysis so they must be on the top-level. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34203753/1297743) for a relevant question.

If you want to load module in runtime, you should not use `import` for it. But you can do it with `System.import` instead

```
System.import('src/app.js').then(function() {
   // deal with app.js
});
```

Comment: Well, how does your `app.js` look like?

Comment: app.js simply imports angular and other angular components

Comment: If your app.js uses `import` statements, it should be fine, SystemJS parses and loads it before module itself.