# How to effectively use ES6 imports in AngularJS application?

Tags: angularjs, architecture, ecmascript-6

With ES5, I realize that most people include all their components with HTML tags like `<script src="app/listCtrl.js"></script>` and attach the component in the same file it is declared.

This is not so straightforward with ES6 imports because imports are hoisted [and that causes the **Angular module to be undefined** when a imported file is trying to attach the component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446635/how-to-es6-import-systemjs-after-some-code).

What I have done *that works* is to import the components and attach them components in main module file.

```
import sidebarDirective from 'app/sidebar/sidebarDirective.js';

angular.module('courseSelector')
  .directive('sidebar', sidebarDirective)
   ...
```

However, this is no better than just using HTML, if I have a "feature" that is multiple components, such as in John Papa's example:

[image: File Structure]

Is there a more elegant solution, which allows me to not have to attach all the components with one file?

---

<sub>been struggling for a while. Thanks</sub>

### **UPDATE**

John Papa does tend to lean towards fewer Angular modules in [this seed](https://github.com/johnpapa/HotTowel-Angular/tree/master/NuGet/HotTowel-NG). The image above is from the blog post, [Angular Structure: Refactoring for growth](http://www.johnpapa.net/angular-growth-structure/). However, in that post, he also writes

> When i see common functionality that can be extracted and re-used, I like to break that out into its own module. In the structure by feature notice that I have a common folder. In there I have another module named common that contains logging, progress bars, and other common features. Sometimes I break this out such that the modules are the first folder under the app folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was to create for each component an own angular module, so that they are really decoupled and dependencies are handled on module level between components.

I made two little example components `hello` and `main` in my boilerplate project: https://github.com/FlorianTopf/angular-seed/tree/master/src.

Have a look into these demo components and the main application module.

Comment: Seems very nice. So you would not agree with Papa in this matter.

Comment: I personally prefer this solution because I see immediately which services, directives, controllers etc. are part of a component. I also don't spoil my ES6 classes with angular.module stuff. However to be able to compare I would need to look into John Papa's example. Can you point me there?

Comment: I added John Papa's example to my question