# ignore eslint error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

Tags: lint, eslint

Is it possible to deactivate this error in eslint?

```
Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level
```

Comment: This is looking like a won't fix scenario.  See https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/2259 and also https://github.com/eslint/espree/issues/124 ; particularly, the quote from the dev at the end of 124, saying he basically sees no reason to support invalid syntax.

Comment: See also:[Why must import / export declarations be top level in es2015?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34203325/why-must-export-import-declarations-be-on-top-level-in-es2015)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

ESLint natively doesnt support this because this is against the spec. But if you use `babel-eslint` parser then inside your eslint config file you can do this:

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
    "allowImportExportEverywhere": true
  }
}
```

Doc ref: https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint#configuration

Comment: Didn't seem like babel-eslint was needed

Comment: non-top-level imports are now part of the spec AND pervasively used

Comment: it's now supported by esline check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58104827/912325)

Answer (score 38):

my solution incase other dont work

```
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module"
}
```

Comment: I can confirm this solution worked and can also be found [here](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-eslint/issues/462)

Answer (score 20):

Support for dynamic import has been added in [eslint 6.2](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/releases/tag/v6.2.0).

You need to set ecmaVersion to 11 (or 2020) though.

```
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 11
    ...
}
```

You can test that in their [online demo](https://eslint.org/demo#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).

Comment: Would it work like this?   "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app",
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 11
}
  },

Comment: That alone didn't work for me, I had to add the following line too - "sourceType": "module"

Comment: it does work in the online demo with `sourceType: script`

Comment: This is a more update to date answer.

Answer (score 4):

In my case:

Added javascriptreact for a react project. I guess the project type should be added to the plugins.

```
{
...,
 "plugins": [
        "prettier",
        "javascriptreact"
    ],
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add this to your eslint file:

```
env: {
  browser: true,
  commonjs: true,
  module: true,
  es2021: true,
  node: true,
 },
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?