# ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, visual-studio-code, browserify

I am learning these stuff as I go. I have setup a project using this as an example:
https://github.com/remojansen/ts-vscode-boilerplate

My project is `TypeScript` and the output must run in the browser (as well as `node.js` but for now browser is the priority).

Have this build target which is supposed to create the output JS that I want:

```
gulp.task("build", function() {

    var libraryName = "webgl";
    var mainTsFilePath = "test/test_gpu_matmul.ts";
    var outputFolder   = "dist/";
    var outputFileName = libraryName + ".js";

    var bundler = browserify({
        debug: true,
        standalone : libraryName
    });

    return bundler
        .add(mainTsFilePath)
        .bundle()
        .on('error', function (error) { console.error(error.toString()); })
        .pipe(source(outputFileName))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))        
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(outputFolder));
});
```

However the gulp build produces the following:

```
D:\repos\webgl\test\test_gpu_matmul.ts:1
import { GpuBackend } from "../src/gpu_backend";
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

Which to me looks like something is not translating from the node.js module format to something browser-compatible.

I searched online and came across one suggestion to use `babelify`. 
[SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' - Wait what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029113)

That thing is a nightmare to install. I tried upgrading to `npm3` and it still didn't work. Please do not suggest that to me.

Here's my tsconfig:

```
{
    "include" : [
        "src",
        "test"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2015", "dom"
        ],
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "noUnusedParameters": false,
        "pretty": true,
        "allowUnreachableCode": false,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' - Wait what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029113/syntaxerror-import-and-export-may-appear-only-with-sourcetype-module-w)

Comment: I have looked at that link and as I mention in my issue babelify does not work for me

Comment: I agree that babelify is a pain to install, but it's probably the correct solution.  Saying "please do not suggest that to me" isn't as productive as asking for help installing babelify correctly in whatever framework you are using.