# Getting error while trying to use typescript with cypress: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Tags: cypress

Getting the following error while trying to use typescript with cucumber feature file. Everything works fine if I change the `.ts` to `.js`. Error also seems clueless.

```
SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
    at EventEmitter.handler (C:\Users\A527629\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\3.2.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\plugins\util.js:67:29)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\Local\Cypress\Cache\3.2.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\plugins\util.js:25:29)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:768:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:141:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

I referred the [url](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor#typescript) to configure it.

More details about the set up can be found at - [url](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/issues/163)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' - Wait what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029113/syntaxerror-import-and-export-may-appear-only-with-sourcetype-module-w)

Comment: You seem to be using cypress 3.2.0. Build in TS support in Cypress is only available since v4.4.0. For me, upgrading fixed this issue!