# 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: "module"' (16:0)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docusaurus

### Background

I am using docusaurus `^1.14.0`. I am using React only. In my `pages`, I try to separate the components by importing a component from another file using a basic `import` statement. However when I try `yarn start` I get the following error:

`'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: "module"' (16:0)`

### Already Tried

I think babel is already setup in the official GitHub repository of docusaurus, so I hope it should work fine with es2015+ syntax which it doesn't.

#### Files

**1. `package.json`**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "examples": "docusaurus-examples",
    "start": "docusaurus-start",
    "build": "docusaurus-build",
    "publish-gh-pages": "docusaurus-publish",
    "write-translations": "docusaurus-write-translations",
    "version": "docusaurus-version",
    "rename-version": "docusaurus-rename-version"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "docusaurus": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "license": "BSD-3-Clause"
}
```

So, how do I fix this?

Comment: Are u using webpack and babel for transpiling and building?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029113/syntaxerror-import-and-export-may-appear-only-with-sourcetype-module-g/40029232#40029232

Comment: try this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029113/syntaxerror-import-and-export-may-appear-only-with-sourcetype-module-g/40029232#40029232

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I will edit the question to add my `package.json`. I certainly know that I have to either configure babel or wepack/babel-loader for this. But in the context of docusaurus, I certainly do not know how to configure them and serve them on the browser.

Comment: Thanks, researched to find that this might work. However docusaurus has no way of doing that. They have abstract scripts of serving, which are only clear through their source code on GitHub. This solution would work in other cases perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Babel and webpack is only used in Docusaurus 2. You're using Docusaurus 1, which doesn't use Babel and only uses a Node.js environment, so by default you can only use CommonJS `require()`s. I recommend checking out [Docusaurus 2](https://v2.docusaurus.io) so that you can use a modern JavaScript setup.