# How To import sanitize.js to react apps Function / class not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've some problem, in my project I need to add [Sanitize.js](https://github.com/gbirke/Sanitize.js) on my project, I've copied to my own 3rd party folder ex vendor
to import it I'm using

```
import  {san} from '../../vendor/Sanitize' //There's No error when compiling this one
```

but there's an error when I run the page, I'm trying to call the function from Sanitize.js as in readme saying to use it just do like this

```
var s = new san.Sanitize({ 
elements:   ['a', 'span'],
attributes: { 
    a: ['href', 'title'], 
    span: ['class'] 
},
protocols:  { 
    a: { href: ['http', 'https', 'mailto'] }
}
});
s.clean_node(p);
```

The Error is

> san.Sanitize is not a function/ class constructor

Any idea why this is happening? or did I miss something? There's no Error in compiling process, the error only occurs when I try to run the web page,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Sanitize.js` is not a module.

Maybe you can try the following solution:

1. Add `export default Sanitize;` in end of `sanitize.js`.
2. Use `import Sanitize from "./sanitize";` to import it.
3. Remove the following code from `sanitize.js`.

```
if ( typeof define === "function" ) {
    define( "sanitize", [], function () { return Sanitize; } );
}
```

Comment: Hi there thank's for the answer, i've trying ur answer still no luck , i get another error
`[12:04:39] 'browserify_typescript' errored after 3.85 s
[12:04:39] SyntaxError in plugin 'gulp-browserify'

/d/Work/nubela/untitled-web/vendor/Sanitize.js:258
export default Sanitize;
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
[12:04:39] 'build-js' errored after 12 s
`

Comment: @dmh Hi, it looks like this is a new question, can you try this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029113/syntaxerror-import-and-export-may-appear-only-with-sourcetype-module-g

Comment: hi thank's for the suggestion, i'm using this `module.exports.Sanitize = Sanitize;` turn out my browserfy dont recognize  export default