# Browserify - ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I would like to make code transpiled by TypeScript to JavaScript be able to run in the browser:

```
ka@Karl-Laptop MINGW64 ~/Development/async (km/client-library)
$ npx browserify ./dist/index.js -t babelify -o ./dist/bundle.js

C:\Users\karl\Development\async\dist\index.js:1
export * from './shared';
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

I read the following: https://babeljs.io/setup#installation via clicking on the browserify button. But it didn't help at all (I installed `npm install --save-dev babelify babel-core --save-exact` and ran `npx browserify ./dist/index.js -t babelify -o ./dist/bundle.js`, same error).

`./dist/index.js` file:

```
export * from './shared';
export * from './client';
export * from './server';
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

`tsconfig.js` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "ES2015",
        "declaration": true,
        "lib": ["ES2016", "ES2017", "ES2018", "ES2019", "ES2018", "ES2019", "ES2020", "dom"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "removeComments": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "types": ["node", "jest"]
    },
    "exclude": ["./dist/", "./coverage/", "./report/"],
    "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

So from TypeScript -> Javascript -> ES5. As per usual I'm guessing Babel is needed to be configured but I am lost as to what exactly it needs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' - Gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029113/syntaxerror-import-and-export-may-appear-only-with-sourcetype-module-g)

Comment: Alternatively in your case you could change the module type emitted by TSC: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did read that and no unfortunately, I did read everything else I could get my hands on. I tried adding the presets they mentioned.

Comment: Please show your research in the question, and give a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ah yes that would probably be the correct approach to change to commonjs and let browserify. Post and answer and I'll accept.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the *correct* approach; the TypeScript docs suggest using `tsify`, for example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/integrating-with-build-tools.html#browserify, which would mean you didn't have two steps. If that change works for you I'm happy for you to post your own answer.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `tsify` worked perfectly!