# Treeshaking BabaylonJs with parcel.js

Tags: babylonjs, parceljs

I have an ES6 web application using multiple libraries (eg BabylonJs, React, Material-UI, Material-Tables).

Transpiling this application without tree shaking works (and even the app does).

But transpiling it with  --experimental-scope-hoisting produces:

```
 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: "module"' (1:0)
```

How do I get this resolved?

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029113/syntaxerror-import-and-export-may-appear-only-with-sourcetype-module-g) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Parcel2 solved my problem.

In a second step I changed to esbuild which dramatically reduced the build time.