# Module build failed: SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

Tags: webpack

In webpack release v2.1.0-beta.28 they added (I'm using 2.2.0-rc.1):

> add `import()` as Code Splitting construct. It should be used instead of
>   `System.import` when possible. System.import will be deprecated in
>   webpack 2 release (removed in webpack 3) as it's behavior is incorrect
>   according to the spec.

So i converted:

```
require.ensure(['./hero/homepage'], () => {
  require('./hero/homepage')
}, 'hero-homepage')
```

Into:

```
import('./hero/homepage')
  .then(module => module.default)
  .catch(err => console.error(`Chunk loading failed, ${err}`))
```

But get: `Module build failed: SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level`

Is there something i have to add to the webpack config to allow imports to be used where they suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per:

https://twitter.com/addyosmani/status/811958786273333248 and  https://twitter.com/usefulthink/status/811958593100587009

The answer is you'll need [babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack](https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack)

Comment: instead of converting import to require-ensure why not modify eslint rule a bit with babel-eslint. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39158552/ignore-eslint-error-import-and-export-may-only-appear-at-the-top-level