# How to include JavaScript libraries only in production build files of create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm trying to add a JavaScript library that is only included in the production build files generated by [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).

What's the best way to do this?

Specifically, I'm trying to include the [Rollbar.js](https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar.js) client-side error monitoring library. I don't want it triggering every time I get an error in development/testing environments, so I only want it included in the files that are generated while running `npm run build`.

Comment: Is checking against `process.env.NODE_ENV` sufficient? i.e. a conditional require? This is how you would normally do things like including devtools only for development, etc.

Comment: Can you paste some of what you've tried?

Comment: I've tried including their "Quick start browser" `<script>` in my `public/index.html` file, but this runs regardless of my environment or whether I've build the production files in the `build` folder.

I've also tried conditionally adding `const Rollbar = require('rollbar');` based on the `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable to `index.js`, but I cannot use a `require` statement before my other `import` statements, and this specific library must be loaded before React and ReactDOM are loaded.

Quick start browser script: https://rollbar.com/docs/notifier/rollbar.js/#quick-start-browser

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I meant that you should modify the question itself by pasting code snippets of things you've tried. As for the script tag approach, you could use a different index.html file when building for production. Your second claim I'm skeptical of and I'd like to see specifically what you tried so that I can test it and make a suggestion.

Comment: However I see you've solved your problem so no worries :)

Comment: Samo - `import` statements must always be declared first in ES2015. See also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34203325/why-must-export-import-declarations-be-on-top-level-in-es2015. If you doubt it, use the create-react-app CLI to make an app and try inserting `const Rollbar = require('rollbar');` before the `import` statements of `index.js`.

Comment: I don't doubt that, but your first statement could easily import a local file that then uses a conditional require on rollbar.

Comment: I tried this and couldn't get it to work. Let me know if you can get it working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer provided by tpdietz is a very good one and would probably work well for many libraries.

However, this specific library I'm trying to use (Rollbar) needs to be loaded before any other JavaScript (e.g. React and ReactDOM), or else it can't capture all errors. Since those other libraries are loaded via `import` statements, I can't use a `require` statement in front of them at the top of `index.js`.

The solution I found (thanks to [GitHub user rokob](https://github.com/rokob) with the Rollbar.js project) is to reference the `NODE_ENV` variable from within the `index.html` file, as described here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#referencing-environment-variables-in-the-html

At the top of my `index.html` file, in a `<script>` tag, I can set a variable to `%NODE_ENV%`. The build process for create-react-app will automatically parse that variable and insert the name of the environment, e.g. "production" or "development", in the final `index.html` file. Then, I can check to see if that variable is equal to "production" before executing any inline JavaScript.

Example `index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script>
    var environment = "%NODE_ENV%";
    if (environment === "production") {
      // code here will only run when index.html is built in production environment
      // e.g. > $ NODE_ENV="production" npm run build
    }
  </script>
```

In the specific case of Rollbar.js, I just needed to pass a config parameter with the environment name, so no `if` statement is necessary:

```
var _rollbarConfig = {
  ...
  enabled: ('%NODE_ENV%' === 'production')  //returns true if 'production'
  ...
};
```

Here is the issue on Github where rokob gave me this solution: https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar.js/issues/583

Answer (score 4):

You can use environment variables.  For example:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  const Rollbar = require('rollbar');
}
```

You can invoke the build command like with a `NODE_ENV` var like so:

```
NODE_ENV="production" npm run build
```

Its worth noting you cannot conditionally use `import` syntax.

Comment: I think he wants this only in production.

Comment: Changed "development" to "production" :) ty

Comment: Thank you; this is very helpful. However, Rollbar specifically must be loaded before any other libraries, e.g. React and ReactDOM. When I try to add `const Rollbar = require('rollbar');` before the other `import` statements in my `index.js` file, I get errors.