# JavaScript: Import file from imported file

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, import, electron

How can I import a class from another file within a file imported by a module in electron (or is this just the completly wrong way and you shouldn't do nested imports; and if, what you should do instead)?

If I try, I get the following error:
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**

That is the example code:

```
//index.html
...
<script src="script1.js" type="module"></script>
...

//script1.js
import Class1 from './script2.js';
const class1 = new Class1();

//script2.js
class Class1 {
  constructor() {
    //doStuff
    import Class2 from './script3.js';
    const class2 = new Class2();
  }
}
export default Class1;

//script3.js
class Class2 {
  constructor() {
    //doStuff
    console.log("Class2");
  }
}
export default Class2;
```

Comment: I think this should answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34203325/why-must-export-import-declarations-be-on-top-level-in-es2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot Anurag! To make the solution more prominent, I post the solution here again:

**The import statement has to be on top level of the file and not inside the class.**

Read this question and the answer for details about the reasons: [Why must export/import declarations be on top level in es2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34203325/why-must-export-import-declarations-be-on-top-level-in-es2015)